# Velocity Engine init() is not initializing

Tags: java, velocity

```
try{
   VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
   ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
   ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
   ve.init();
//Tried by using properties also
/*
java.util.Properties p = new java.util.Properties();
p.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER,ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
p.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class",ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
p.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.class","org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem");
ve.init(p);
*/
}
catch(Exception ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

even exception is not showing that I can understand what is needed.
I am using this to get the SMS template.

Comment: How do you know it's not initializing?

Comment: In time of debug ve.init() it shows no attached source found and my next line of code is not executing. Anyway it should throw exception but it is not coming to catch.

Comment: "no attached source found" is just an IDE debugger problem, it doesn't mean your code isn't working.

Comment: "apache-velocity-velocity-1.5.jar has no source attachment. You can attach the source by clicking Attach Source below" - Where can I find this source to attach? Is it talking about to add jar(I added already).?

Comment: Get it here:  http://velocity.apache.org/download.cgi